# weak claw-free graphs

Tags: graph-theory

The complete bipartite graph $K_{1,3}$ is known as a claw-graph. A graph $G$ is said to be claw-free it doesn't have an induced subgraph isomorphic to the claw-graph.

We define a graph to be weak claw-free if it doesn't have a subgraph isomorphic to the claw graph. It is immediate that the maximum degree of any vertex in this graph will be equal to two.

I am interested in the question, what more can be said about the structure of such simple graphs and any references regarding this notion will also very helpful.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: If the graph is simple, then this is equivalent to the existence of a vertex of degree $3$ or more.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks. is there any name for the collection of graphs whose maximal vertex degree is fixed $k$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know. Graph theory is not really my area. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit No problem. Thank you. Your observation was helpful.

Comment: "Weak claw-free" is a funny name for a condition that is **stronger** than "claw-free".

Comment: Why do you say the maximum degree "will be equal to two"? Seems to me all you can say is "less than or equal to two". For instance, the graph consisting of two vertices joined by an edge is "weak claw free" and its maximum degree is one.

Comment: In fact, a (simple) graph is "weak claw-free" IF AND ONLY IF it has maximum degree $\le2$. (We ARE talking about simple graphs, aren't we? Otherwise a weak claw-free graph could have degree greater than two, for instance, two vertices joined by a hundred edges.)

Comment: A simple graph is "weak claw-free" if and only if each connected component is eithat a path or a cycle.

Comment: @bof Thank you. "Weak claw-free" is a weaker notion no? because weak claw-free implies claw-free.

Comment: "Weak claw-free" is stronger than "claw-free" because "weak claw-free" implies "claw-free".

Comment: In graph theory, "strongly regular" implies "regular", "strongly connected" implies "connected". In set theory, "strongly inaccessible" implies "weakly inaccessible", "strongly compact" implies "weakly compact".

Comment: Thanks. perfect. Now I understood :) .